# my jQuery parameter is not recognized by the C# method in which is accessed in script area

Tags: javascript, c#

I tried to access the my C# method in my JavaScript, but this method is not accepting the local parameters and saying, the parameter does not exist in the current context.

```
var typeofServiceNumber = $("#serviceType").val();
@MyStaticClass.StringEncoding(Convert.ToString(typeofServiceNumber));
```

The above `typeofServiceNumber` is not recognized by the method

Answer (score 2):

Razor code is executed server side before the HTML is returned in the response stream.

Javascript is executed client side within the resultant HTML.

Therefore you cannot pass a Javascript variable through to a Razor method, and you receive the message that typeOfServiceNumber is not recognized.

To be recognized, it would either need to be handled server side via data being passed to the View (ViewBag, Model etc), or it would need to be declared and assigned to within Razor tags on the page itself.

EDIT: to clarify the last point:

```
var typeofServiceNumber = $("#serviceType").val();
@MyStaticClass.StringEncoding(Convert.ToString(typeofServiceNumber))
```

The first line you have here is all happening in the browser of the end user.

The second line is all happening on the server.  You see the error message because you are trying to pass "typeofServiceNumber" to your method, and the variable isn't even declared at that point.

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve it's hard for me to give a precise answer as to how to solve your problem.  But here are two possibilities:

1) You know what `$("#serviceType").val()` is going to be before you serve the web page to the end user because that value is being set server side.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult MysteryController()
{
   ...your code here to work out what the service type is...

   ViewBag.serviceType = serviceType;

   return View();
}
```

View:

```
...lots of lovely html and such...

<script>
  @MyStaticClass.StringEncoding(Convert.ToString(ViewBag["serviceType"]));
</script>
```

I can't see what the output of `@MyStaticClass.StringEncoding()` is but I have to assume at this point that it is doing whatever it is supposed to do.

Although the logic is split between the controller and the view, all of this is happening server side.

The second half of my point "*or it would need to be declared and assigned to within Razor tags on the page itself.*" refers to the fact that one variation of this method could involve manipulating data in the View itself by enclosing it in a Razor code block like this:

```
@{
   var typeofServiceNumber = @MyStaticClass.StringEncoding(Convert.ToString(ViewBag["serviceType"]));    
}
```

The alternative, which I did not really address originally is:

2) You don't know what the value of `$("#serviceType").val()` is going to be before the page is loaded because it is being set by the end user and your function needs to be used before the data is submitted to the server:

If that's the case then `@MyStaticClass.StringEncoding(Convert.ToString(typeofServiceNumber))` is no good to you, you will have to replicate the function in JavaScript and include it in the webpage itself.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the answer, i dint that 4th point, can you pls explain little clearly

Comment: I have expanded my answer to hopefully provide a bit more clarity